# c++ deleting char pointer allocated with new

Tags: c++, char, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

In this code I am getting numbers from a file, when the first number is the size of the 2D array.

In my code I'm defining

```
char *filename=new char;
```

(I have to use char *filename, this is the exercise..)
Everything works fine, until the moment I try to `delete`. both `delete` and `delete[]` gives me error and crashing my program.

This is my full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
double **readmat(char *filename, int *size)/////question 2
{
    ifstream read(filename);
    cout << filename << endl;
    if (!read)
    {
        cout << "Can't open file!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    read >> *size;
    double **mat = new double*[*size];
    for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++)
    {
        mat[i] = new double[*size];
        for (int j = 0; j < *size; j++)
        {
            read >> mat[i][j];
        }
    }    
    read.close();    
    return mat;
}
int main()
{
    int size;
    char *filename = new char;
    filename = "text.txt"; 

    double **arr = readmat(filename, &size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j]<<"  ,  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    delete filename; //<-------- this crashed my code
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        delete[] arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}
```

This is how my file looks:

[image]

This is what the console app looks like after running the code:

[image]

Which is what I am expecting to get, but I get this error:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what could this happen, and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: You immediately overwrite the address held by `char *filename = new char;` by assigning the address of the string literal `filename = "text.txt";`. Ask yourself "Where does `filename` now point?"

Comment: **You are allocating ONE character** for `filename`.  You may want to consider allocating more, like 64 or 128.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to `delete` a `char*` that is not pointing at memory allocated with `new`.

On this line:

```cpp
char *filename = new char;
```

You do `new` some memory (a single `char`, not a string of `char`s).  But then on this line:

```cpp
filename = "text.txt";
```

You change the `char*` pointer to point at completely different memory, thus leaking the memory you `new`'ed.

Then on this line:

```
delete filename;
```

You try to `delete` the `"text.txt"` literal, not the `char` you `new`'ed.  That is why you crash.

For what you are attempting to do, you need to do this instead:

```cpp
char *filename = new char[strlen("text.txt")+1];
strcpy(filename, "text.txt");
...
delete[] filename;
```

However, you really should not be using `new`/`new[]` for `filename` at all.  Use `std::string` instead:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

double **readmat(const std::string &filename, int *size)
{
    std::ifstream read(filename.c_str());
    ...
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    double **arr = readmat("text.txt", &size);
    ...
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

double **readmat(const char *filename, int *size)
{
    ifstream read(filename);
    ...
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    std::string filename = "text.txt";

    double **arr = readmat(filename.c_str(), &size);
    // or simply:
    // double **arr = readmat("text.txt", &size);
    ...
}
```

And then, while you are at it, you should not be using `new[]` for your matrix, either.  Use `std::vector` instead:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector< std::vector<double> > readmat(char *filename)
{
    ...

    int size;
    read >> size;

    std::vector< std::vector<double> > mat(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        mat[i].resize(size);
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            read >> mat[i][j];
        }
    }    

    return mat;
}

int main()
{
    ...

    std::vector< std::vector<double> > arr = readmat("text.txt");
    size_t size = arr.size();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            std::cout << arr[i][j] << "  ,  ";
        }
        std::cout << endl;
    }
    std::cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
char *filename = new char;
filename = "text.txt";
```

This creates a new char, then leaks it because the pointer `filename` is reassigned to something that is statically declared.

Therefore, later on you delete something else than the original char.

Multiple issues here (using new instead of new[], etc). Suggestion, forget *everything* and use std::string and STL.

Answer (score 3):

This is the source of your problem:

```
char *filename = new char;
filename = "text.txt";
```

`filename` no longer points to dynamically allocated memory, thus you can't `delete` it (and you're also leaking 1 byte of memory). Change your declaration to `const char *filename = "test.txt";` and remove the `delete filename;`.

Answer (score 2):

`new char` allocates a *single* character on the heap. Most functions that take a `const char*` as parameter expect a pointer to the first element of an *array* with the null character (`\0`) as delimiter (a C-style string).

You shouldn't even be able to assign a string literal to a variable of type `char *`, at least not in standard C++. You also don't need to dynamically allocate memory for string literals, simply use

```
const char *filename = "text.txt";
```

Then you also don't delete pointers to string literals. (That's what causes the error most likely, you deleted a pointer that pointed to a string literal)

Comment: "*You shouldn't even be able to assign a string literal to a variable of type `char *`, at least not in standard C++*" - you can in C++ versions prior to C++11. But you are right, this is not good practice. String literals should be assigned to `const char*` instead, and C++11 and later enforce that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Intersting, didn't kow that :)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
char* filename = new char;
```

with

```
const char* filename = "text.txt";
```

and remove

```
delete filename;
```

This is how your final code will look

```
int main()
{
    int size;
    const char *filename = "text.txt"; 

    double **arr = readmat(filename, &size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j]<<"  ,  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        delete[] arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}
```